# Pass arguments to PhantomJS script through PHP exec?

Tags: php, phantomjs

There was already a question similar to this, however it didn't quite answer the question.

So my question is, if I have a PhantomJS script which is executed via `exec` in PHP, could I also pass some arguments to it which the PhantomJS script could then somehow get and use? If so, how would I pass them from the PHP and how would I use them in the PhantomJS script? If not, is there any other way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question you're referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following in PHP:

```
$response = exec('/path/to/phantomjs myscript.js arg1 arg2');
```

Then read the arguments from `system.args` (as documented in http://phantomjs.org/api/system/property/args.html)

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
  console.log(i + ': ' + arg);
});
```

Comment: Great answer, but please note that this way of running exec will only put one last line of output in $response.

Comment: Any ideas why this PHP doesn't return anything? PHP: `echo exec('~/usr/bin/phantomjs --version');` ? It is indeed there: https://gyazo.com/663a1b302dcfd894c21ff6f072853c52

Comment: Ah, stupid me haha, you don't need to specify root, /usr/bin/phantomjs worked. Thanks again man, really happy I got my phantomjs working.